# Flsun Q5 returns 'ok 0' as response to every command

Tags: marlin, g-code, serial-connection, python

I have a **Flsun Q5** which I am trying to get to communicate with my python script. The script is this:

```
import serial
from time import sleep

COMMAND = 'M105' # Request for temperature


ser = serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=115200)
print('Connected to Printer... T-2s\n')
sleep(2)
ser.write(f'{COMMAND}\n'.encode('utf-8'))
print(f'>>> {COMMAND}')
sleep(20)  # Allow time for response
response = ser.readline()
print(response.decode('ascii'))
```

But it returns `ok 0` everytime (even when asked for firmware i.e., `M115`):

```
>>> M105
ok 0
```

When I hit with a `G28` command, the printer does move like its supposed to, but it responds with `ok 0`. It's like it responds like that to everything. I have tried messing with that **20s** timeout, but no matter what, it does not do anything.

How do I get the temperature of the bed? TIA.